# Windows 7 Sleep Power settings

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power-management

[image: CONTEXT: Windows 7 Power Settings]

Last night I was running a lengthy series of jobs: the intent was to have them run overnight: the machine is plugged-in and NOT running on battery power.  I woke up this morning to find the PC had been put into sleep mode for some reason and the jobs were NOT finished.

Is there another setting that needs to be considered or is there a good place to start troubleshooting as to why the machine shutdown on its own?

Any suggestions to improve the question is appreciated. I can not be the only person to suffer this problem: re-opening with an improve question will help future users

Comment: This is a laptop? If yes, had you closed the lid?

Comment: Good question: no the lid was never closed.  That would invoke sleep mode and prevent overnight execution of the jobs

Comment: "is there a good place to start troubleshooting as to why the machine shutdown on its own?" Yes, the event logs.

Comment: When you click on Change advanced power settings you have 2 options that you need to check: sleep = never and hard-disk= never turn off.

Comment: @Alex That is in the image of the question. What are you suggesting to the OP?

Comment: There are several power settings that need to be checked/modified by going to the advanced power settings, as I stated in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Check the advanced power plan settings by clicking on `Change advanced power settings`:
[image]

In the menu that opens you have to check if your HDD is set to turn off after 0 minutes (never):
[image]

and if Sleep and Hybrid sleep are off:

[image]